# How to convert SparkR dataframe to local R data table?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am changing a local R script to sparkR. The input is hive table and I read the table using the code as following:

```
>sparkR.session()
>results <- sql("SELECT * FROM temp.temp_ceshi limit 3")
>head(results)
```

[image]

```
>typeof(results)
[1] "S4"
```

And the local R script uses `fread` to read the csv files. I want to convert the sparkR dataframe to data.table and use the local R script. How to make it?

Comment: Don't use `typeof`. Use `str` instead. Much more informative.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `collect()` function:

```
>results_df <- collect(results)
```

You can also read more about conversion by the link:
https://markobigdata.com/2016/03/26/sparkr-and-r-dataframe-and-data-frame/

Comment: This question is how to convert SparkR to a data.table, not a dataframe. Linked article doesn't mention `data.table` at all